# Need a more graceful pattern for shutting down TcpListener

Tags: c#, network-programming, tcpclient, tcplistener

I have a `TcpListener` that when shutting down causes all in-progress clients to throw the below exception when they try and call `EndAcceptTcpClient`. Is there a more graceful pattern I can use to allow all existing client connections to finish before the TcpListener is completely shut down?

> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
>   Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.Socket'.    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndAccept(IAsyncResult asyncResult)    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener.EndAcceptTcpClient(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)

Here is a sample of the listener setup:

```
private TcpListener _requestListener;
```

---

```
requestListener = new TcpListener(endPoint);

requestListener.Start(1000);

requestListener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(ServiceRequestInstanceHandler, null);
```

When I'm trying to close down the listener I call the following. This is what leads to the aforementioned exception.

```
if (_requestListener != null)
{
    _requestListener.Stop();
}
```

Here is an example of the code that is handling callbacks which are ultimately effected by calling the listeners `Stop()` method

```
private void ServiceRequestInstanceHandler(IAsyncResult result)
{
    try
    {
        using (TcpClient client = _requestListener.EndAcceptTcpClient(result))
        {
            ProcessRequest(client);
            client.Close();
        }

        //Prepare to accept the next message
        _requestListener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(ServiceRequestInstanceHandler, null);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (_logger.IsErrorEnabled)
            _logger.Error("An error occured while processing a service request. ", ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe to avoid the error, you need to pass in your `requestListener` object to the `BeginAcceptTcpClient` like so:

```
requestListener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(ServiceRequestInstanceHandler, requestListener);
```

For Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.beginaccepttcpclient.aspx

I would also, personally, re-write your method to allow your server to accept a new client before processing the other client like so:

```
private void ServiceRequestInstanceHandler(IAsyncResult result)
{
try
    {
        // You should probably check for a null result here, just in case
        if(result == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Result is null, cannot continue");
        }
        using (TcpClient client = _requestListener.EndAcceptTcpClient(result))
        {
            // Remember this line returns immediately/does not block
            _requestListener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(ServiceRequestInstanceHandler, _requestListener);
            ProcessRequest(client);
            client.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (_logger.IsErrorEnabled)
            _logger.Error("An error occured while processing a service request. ", ex);
    }
}
```

IIRC, the async stuff runs on a separate thread.

**Note:** I have not tested the above code, but it should solve your problem :)

HTH

Comment: Couple questions... (**1**) Since the `_requestListener` is never `null` this would still result in the same error wouldn't it? (**2**) Even if I set it to `null` after stopping it, wouldn't that prevent me from finishing a request we have already received, and remove any possibility of me communicating back to the requestor that the *received* request will not be processed?

Comment: @StuartBlacker Sorry, I mis-read this. I see what you mean, and I will make that change although I still don't see how to handle in-flight requests.

Comment: @JoeGeeky, `BeginAcceptTcpClient` in your code has two parameters, callback and state. In the documentation it shows that you need to pass the `TcpListener` so that it knows which TcpListener to end the accept on. So if you pass null for the state and try casting it back you are accessing a null (in this case disposed) object.  Again, I haven't tested so my memory could be wrong, but I suspect that's the case. Does that make sense?

Comment: This won't fix the "problem." `ObjectDisposedException` is thrown on `_requestListener.EndAcceptTcpClient()` once `Stop()` has been called and is the expected behavior. This is how you break our listener out of the `BeginAcceptTcpClient()` wait that it is in. You only need to pass in the `requestListener` to the `Begin*()` method if you intend to pull it out of `result.AsyncState`. If you pass in `null` to `Begin*()` and then try to read `result.AsyncState` you'll get a null pointer exception. The passed in state is just for your use... the framework doesn't need it.